# Resending a question if not answered correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline

I have this code like I would like to be able to resend the original question without changing anything if it was not answered correctly.

```
const rl = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

const questionOne = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        rl.question("Say a number: ", (answer) => {
            resolve(answer);
        });
    });
};

(async () => {
    const answerOne = await questionOne();
    await console.log(answerOne);
})();
```

So basically on the "questionOne" function if the answer doesn't return a certain message such as "1" then just resend the original question (Say a number: ) without resolving it.

I've tried stuff such as this:

```
const questionOne = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        rl.question("Say a number: ", (answer) => {
            if (isNaN(answer)) {
                console.log('Wrong.');
                questionOne();
                return;
            }
            resolve(answer);
        });
    });
};
```

and it has not even came close to working.

Comment: hi, where you use an async function you must await the response (success or failure) then you can get the response or call back the async function if there is no result.

Comment: `return questionOne().then(resolve);` at the end of your `if`

Comment: `and it has not even came close to working.`

don't be so hard on yourself, it actually comes very close - it's a one line change (see above) to get it working :)